# Schedule Javascript/jQuery functions throughout the day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a digital building directory which runs a chromeless web browser. I want to execute various Javascript & jQuery functions at specific times of day, initially just to hide and show various objects, but later to do some more advanced actions as well.

I can't use a simple timer, because the events need to be triggered on the hour exactly, or 5 minutes before the hour exactly, etc. AKA, not just "every hour".

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use a simple timer, after you calculated the difference between the current time and the target time:

Example in node.js:

```
> setTimeout(function() { console.log(new Date()); }, (new Date('2014-03-15T02:38:30+0100')).getTime() - Date.now());
{ _idleTimeout: 22653,
  _idlePrev: 
   { _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 22653,
     ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
  _idleNext: 
   { _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 22653,
     ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
  _idleStart: 1394847487347,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _repeat: false }
> Sat Mar 15 2014 02:38:30 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

You can create a timestamp for a specific time using:

```
date = new Date('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+0000'); // adjust the time zone as needed
date.getTime() // e.g. 1394847510000
```

Now subtract `Date.now()` from it and you got the number of milliseconds you have to wait, which you now can pass to `setTimeout`.